# Sage 300 CRE Timberline Data ODBC Driver DELETE Error

Tags: sql-server, c#-4.0, permissions, odbc

I am trying to automate archiving of the Log files generated by sage.  We generate an average of 15,000 log entries a day and the LogViewer in sage is so slow it is nearly unusable after a month.  I am querying the data older than seven days and then inserting it to our SQL Server.  Using the same connection string I can query data from the QLM Master Log but when I go to delete data I get an error.

With my Sage user service account:

ERROR [42000] [Simba][SimbaEngine ODBC Driver][DRM File Library]Access denied.

With my personal Sage user account.  I was failing at opening second connection with this error: (Still not sure why but not directly relevent)

ERROR [08001] [Simba][SimbaEngine ODBC Driver][DRM File Library]Invalid account name.
ERROR [IM006] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Driver's SQLSetConnectAttr failed
ERROR [01000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] The driver doesn't support the version of ODBC behavior that the application requested (see SQLSetEnvAttr).

Once i adjusted my code to no longer attempt a second connection open I get the same error:

ERROR [42000] [Samba][SimbaEngine ODBC Driver][DRM File Library]Access denied.

Any help would be appreciated but I am looking for.

- Is this actually a permissions issue?
- Is the problem with my Windows User account OR Sage user account?
- What access is required to run the delete command?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm getting the same error.

Comment: @jrummell I did not figure it out.  I put together a process document outlining the steps to archive the log file through Sage and gave it to our support team for when people complain about Log Viewer running slowly.  I would prefer automation but at least this way there is a documented process we are following.

Comment: I was able to get this resolved by having my account permissions corrected. The error messages don't really give you much to go on.

Comment: @jrummell What did your account permissions have to be? My Sage account has roles that include Tasks for ODBC read and write access.

Comment: I wish I knew. I'm working as an outside contractor and either my client or his Sage support contact fixed it for me.

Comment: @jrummell You are lucky my conversations with Sage support usually end with "We do not support that functionality".

Answer (score 0):

After speaking with a Sage 300 CRE Certified Consultant I have been informed that data in Log Viewer is not editable via ODBC, and to remove data I have to use the Log Viewer interface.  According to the consultant Sage has an open DLL that would provide the functionality but it would open other areas of the program as well and they do not give it out normally.

Though it runs somewhat counter to jrummell's comments this is what I was told; the expert has spoken the project is officially at a dead end pending the acquisition of this open DLL.

I will let the community know if any additional information pertaining to this question is uncovered.